# How to display a messagebox once all the items in the Tkinter listbox is selected?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Ive coded a gui call script with each line being an item in the listbox. I want a messagebox to tell the user that all the items in the listbox are completed. please assist if possible.

```
list = Listbox(window, selectmode = "multiple", font = ("Consolas", 20), width=100, cursor='dot', yscrollcommand = yscrollbar.set)  
list.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=15, padx=10, sticky='', columnspan=4)

list.insert(0, "Activity 1")
list.insert(1, "Activity 2")
list.insert(2, "Activity 3") 
list.insert(3, "Activity 4")
list.insert(4, "Activity 5")
list.insert(5, "Activity 6")
list.insert(6, "Activity 7")

if int(listbox.size()) == len(listbox.curselection()):
    messagebox.showinfo("Well done!", "You've completed the call script!")
```

I need the messagebox to be displayed once all the items in the listbox are selected
but currently it does nothing, not even an errormessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work as long as it is called whenever there is change in the selections.

Below is a simple example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def on_select(event):
    listbox = event.widget
    if int(listbox.size()) == len(listbox.curselection()):
        messagebox.showinfo("Well done!", "You've completed the call script!")

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode="multiple", activestyle="none")
listbox.pack()
# call on_select() whenever selection is changed
listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", on_select)

# insert dummy items
for i in range(5):
    listbox.insert("end", i+1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @MogamadZubairIsaacs Yes the messagebox will be shown as soon as all items are selected.  Did you try my code?